# python re sequential replace datetime field in file

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

I have a file with several Date Time fields but it has the same value

```
DateTime = 14-Oct-21  15:25:17
DateTime = 14-Oct-21  15:25:17
DateTime = 14-Oct-21  15:25:17
```

I want replace each entry with an incremented time such that it now reads -

```
DateTime = 14-Oct-21  16:00:00
DateTime = 14-Oct-21  16:03:00
DateTime = 14-Oct-21  16:06:00
```

In order to achieve this, I created a regex pattern that can be used to match the DateTime field in the text file
`pattern = '[\w].* = [\d]{2}-[\w]*-[\d]{2}.*[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}'`.
I have a function that creates a sequentially expanded list of date time fields

```
def time_range(number_of_entries):
    all_time_objects = []
    all_time_objects.append(datetime.now())
    
    for i in range(number_of_entries):
        now_time = all_time_objects[i]
        now_time += timedelta(minutes=3)
        all_time_objects.append(now_time)
    
    formatted_time_list = [datetime.strftime(i,'%d-%b-%y  %H:%M:%S') for i in all_time_objects]
    return formatted_time_list
```

In order to replace each entry in the text file I am performing the following operations

```
pattern = '[\w].* = [\d]{2}-[\w]*-[\d]{2}.*[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}:[\d]{2}'
date_time_list = time_range(3)
with open(src_file, 'r') as src:
    filedata = src.read()

for i in range(len(date_time_list)):
        new = re.sub(pattern, 'DateTime = ' +date_time_list[i], filedata)
```

However, this results in only the last value from the `date_time_list` being used for the substitution.

How do I get re.sub to match the first match with the first replacement and so on?

Comment: I think this is because you are overwriting `new = ` on every iteration

Comment: You re-creatr `new` variable upon each iteration. Use comprehension, or declare a new list and `.append` to it.

Comment: The issue is that the `re.sub` is mistakenly assumed to replace only the first instance and track like an io position, whereas it replaces in bulk —so there is no need for a for-loop as said, but it only uses the replacement pattern the once. As a result the solution is to have a function as the replacement, where in that function's block is a global incrementor that iterates across the replacement list.